# ASP .Net File Action Result error 500 on remote client but not on localhost

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

From my view.js, I am uploading a byte[] into an img. It works properly if I execute the client in localhost. However, for a remote client, I am getting "failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500" when executing GetImageLoaded.

```
    var img = document.getElementById("ImageBackground");

    img.src = '/RecipeNew/GetImageLoaded/' + Date.now();
```

viewController.cs gets the byte array and creates a FileContentResult object. And this is what is not working remotely.

```
 public ActionResult GetImageLoaded()
        {
            return File(VOSystem._tempImageLoaded, "image/bmp");
        }
```

Update: I tried several methods but none is working. I really don't want to access to a File. I only want to get the content of a byte array as a result. However base64 string doesn't work so it's a large string.

Comment: Most server default connection to GUEST and do not access to the file system on the server.  Better to put files on a Network drive that users have access to.

Comment: Can you apply some logging and exception handling to get a better idea what is going on? My guess is that VOSystem._tempImageLoaded is not there or access is denied.

Comment: @jdweng but I am not accessing to any file, the byte array comes from an SQL

Comment: @Crowcoder tempImageLoaded is a byte array that comes from a sql register and has information

Comment: OK, but logging and exception handling will still give you more information. You should try to never allow a 500 to return to the client, you can handle errors however you want but the client should get something more meaningful back.

Comment: Doesn't this say FILE : return File(VOSystem._tempImageLoaded, "image/bmp");

Comment: That's my problem, that I would like to get it as a string for example, not a FILE, but is a huge byte array